# Is there a way to download or save voice recordings from messenger?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to download or save a voice recording sent via facebook messenger?  I can't find ANY reference on Google or elsewhere as to how to do this. Seems if you record it from iPhone (Messenger app), it must be stored somewhere - I was hoping it would auto-save to Voice Memos app, but no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on your iPhone itself, but you can on [messenger.com](https://messenger.com) on a Mac.

1. Open messenger.com in Safari and navigate to the voice recording.
2. Open the Web Inspector from the Develop menu (enable from Preferences → Advanced) and choose the Network tab.
3. Play the voice recording.
4. A new row will be added to the Network tab. Double-click the file and it will download.